# Capture a value from a multiple line output

Tags: perl

```
use Control::CLI;
$cli = new Control::CLI('SSH');
$cli->connect(Host=>'10.10.10.10',Username=>'user',Password=>'pwd');
$cli->waitfor('>');
$cli->print('Show XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX| grep Active');
@f=$cli->waitfor('>');
print @f;
$cli->disconnect;
```

The above code give me output as:

```
 Show XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX| grep Active
Active
Sunday January 29 00:40:34 IST 2012
Active                  : 1106          Dormant                 : 0
[local]NOI-S57-XYXYX>
```

But I want to capture only "1106"( in the 3rd line, value between Active: "1106" and Dormant), Please help!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
@myarray = ($f =~ m/(\d+)/g);
print "@myarray['5'] ";
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more specifically, for LINE-4:

```
my $number = $1 if $f[3] =~ m/Active\s+:\s+(\d+)\s+Dormant/;
print defined $number ? "$number\n" : "NONE\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
But this code is not working as per expectation, Please note that the required number is in the 4th line of the output, Sorry that in earlier post i mentioned it in the 3rd line.

Comment: The fourth line (counting 0-relative) is $f[3].  Corrected for your post's correction.

Answer (score 0):

With minimal error checking this should get your number on the third line:

```
if( $f[3] =~ m/(\d+)/ ) {
  printf "Found number on third line: %d\n" , $1 ;
} else {
  print "No number on line 4\n" ;
}
```

Edit: Corrected line number

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But this code is not working as per expectation, Please note that the required number is in the 4th line of the output, Sorry that in earlier post i mentioned it in the 3rd line.

Comment: @user1175590 Typo should be `my @f=$cli->waitfor('>');`

Comment: @user1175590 Start your skripts with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` they will help you find such small errors.